# how to create cache by django + uwsgi?

Tags: django, caching, uwsgi

The code **works in local**, but **not works in server**!
I have a vps (ubuntu): I use uWSGI.

I have a class for management online user.

```
from django.core.cache import cache

class OnlineUser(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
    self.key = key
    self.human_env = Environment(PROBABILITY_ENV)
    self.robot_env = Environment(PROBABILITY_ENV)
    human = Human()
    robot = Agent(configure[COST_MOVEMENT][0], configure[COST_MOVEMENT][1], configure[COST_MOVEMENT][2])
    self.robot_env.agent = robot
    self.human_env.agent = human

    f_learning = 'agent_p%.2f_d%.2f_l%.2f_e%.2f_c%.2d.ai' % (
        PROBABILITY_ENV, configure[COST_MOVEMENT][0], configure[COST_MOVEMENT][1], configure[COST_MOVEMENT][2],
        COST_MOVEMENT)
    f_learning = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'chahchi', f_learning)

    try:
        with open(f_learning, 'rb') as agent_:
            robot.policy = pickle_load(agent_)
    except:
        self.robot_env.learn()
        with open(f_learning, 'wb') as output:
            pickle_dump(robot.policy, output)

    self.update_cache()

    def next_round(self):
       self.human_env.next_round()
       self.robot_env.next_round()

    def update_cache(self):
       cache.set(self.key, self)

    def __eq__(self, other):
       return self.key == other.key

def chahchi(request):
   request.session['chahchi'] = True
   user = OnlineUser(request.session.session_key)

   ground = [[0 for j in xrange(8)] for i in xrange(8)]
   for i, j, value in State.points:
      ground[i][j] = value
   for i, j, in Environment.wells:
      ground[i][j] = -200

   robot = [0, 7]
   return render_to_response('chahchi/chahchi.html', {
    'ground': ground,
    'robot': robot
}, RequestContext(request))

@csrf_exempt
def chahchi_ajax(request):
   user = cache.get(request.session.session_key)
   if not request.session['chahchi']:
      return HttpResponse(status=404)

   human_action = request.POST['action']
   robot_env, human_env = user.robot_env, user.human_env

  if not robot_env.test_info['finish']:
     r_action_name, r_test_info = robot_env.next_step()
  else:
     r_action_name = None
     r_test_info = robot_env.test_info
  if not human_env.test_info['finish']:
     h_action_name, h_test_info = human_env.next_step(action=human_action)
  else:
     h_action_name = None
     h_test_info = human_env.test_info

  if robot_env.test_info['finish'] and human_env.test_info['finish']:
     user.next_round()
     user.update_cache()
  else:
     user.robot_env = robot_env
     user.human_env = human_env
     user.update_cache()

  response_data = {
    'robot': {
        'test_info': r_test_info,
        'action': r_action_name,
    },
    'human': {
        'test_info': h_test_info,
        'action': h_action_name,
    },
    'game': {
        'counter_episode': 0,
        'finish': False
    }
}
   return HttpResponse(json_dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
"mezzanine.core.middleware.UpdateCacheMiddleware",

'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
# Uncomment if using internationalisation or localisation
# 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

"mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.SitePermissionMiddleware",
# Uncomment the following if using any of the SSL settings:
# "mezzanine.core.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware",
"mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware",
"mezzanine.core.middleware.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",)
```

local_settings.py

i test this

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
       'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/django_cache',
    }
}
```

and:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
       'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

but not work correctly in server.

first call function my_view after call my_view_ajax.

when call my_view_ajax, I get error 500,

error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'robot_env'
```

Comment: Please add your CACHES settings.

Comment: Are you sure this works on server? in `my_view_ajax` you have defined no `user`. Where should `user` come from?

Comment: this code works in local (in my editor),  but not work in server!. first call `my_view` after call `my_view_ajax`. so create a user and cache it. after call it.

Comment: There's no way this code could work *anywhere*. Neither of the views return a response, so you would immediately get an error because of that; and, as ilse points out, you have not assigned the result of the cache.get to the user variable, so the following line could not work. Please post *actual* code that shows the problem you are having.

Comment: What about your cache settings? Can't believe this is you full code of `my_ajax_view`...

Comment: I emphasize, the code **works in local**, but **not works in server**!

Comment: Now it looks more like a possible working code, but again please add your `CACHES` settings from settings.py. What cache backend are you using?

Comment: There is no point claiming your code works locally, but posting code that cannot possibly work. Thanks for updating it to actually working code. However you have still not shown enough to help: what is responsible for putting the user into the cache in the first place? (And, we might ask, why do you want to cache the user at all?)

Comment: I have a game. I need to cache for each individual case management. If I want every person in the playground I save my files is very slow. [my game](http://roomana.ir/project/chahchi/play/) now works for only one user!, I think we need more of an effort.